# Should the reputation tag be edited to cover questions about individuals too?

Tags: discussion, tags

By reading the [tag excerpt](https://academia.stackexchange.com/tags/reputation/info) about [reputation](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reputation);

> The perception of the quality of a journal, conference, or university
>   by a specific community or the general public. Also: how reputation
>   develops and factors influencing reputation.

it seems that this tag only covers questions about reputation of journals and research institutes; all *but* individuals. By reading a recent question about the reputation of individuals;

[How to judge the reputation of a research group or professor for good quality research for PhD?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/28827/how-to-judge-the-reputation-of-a-research-group-or-professor-for-good-quality-re)

this question comes to mind that;

```
Does this tag cover questions about persons too?
```

If it should not be used, the question should be edited and if it is allowed on the questions about people's reputation, we should change this tag's excerpt.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that list ("journal, conference, or university") was ever meant to be exclusive.

In any event, now it reads:

> The perception of the quality of a journal, conference, university, or other academic entity by a specific community or the general public. Also: how reputation develops and factors influencing reputation.

so as to not exclude questions about the reputation of: an individual, research group, department, group of universities, type of journal (e.g. open access), publisher, preprint repository, or anything else that might be relevant to academia.

Answer (score 0):

There are currently (April 2020) 94 questions with this tag and it is used inconsistently. The alternatives seem to be to edit the wiki to include *personal-reputation* as well or to create a new tag for that. At the moment the solution is tractable either way. But journal reputation and personal reputation or academic reputation seem very different.

I suggest that this needs some resolution. The [answer of ff524](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1274/75368) suggests expanding the definition. I'd be fine with that, but would like some guidance first.